# Класс, считающий количество созданных им инстансов

Tags: python, ооп, классы, python-2.x

Требуется написать класс, который считает количество созданных им инстансов.
Метод класса `get_created_instances_count()` должен возвращать это число.

код должен пройти эту проверку:

```
class CreatedInstancesCounter(object):
# писать решение сюда #
pass


if TEST:
    for i in xrange(56):
        CreatedInstancesCounter()

    assert CreatedInstancesCounter.get_created_instances_count() == 56
    CreatedInstancesCounter()
    assert CreatedInstancesCounter.get_created_instances_count() == 57
    print 'Task 2 OK'
```

Comment: Маркус, на этом ресурсе не решают задачи за других. Напишите, что вы пробовали и на чем застряли.

Comment: Уже хорошо. Вы понимаете, в чем отличие `get_created_instances` от обычного метода?

Comment: Именно. Если мне не изменяет память, для этого достаточно декоратора `@classmethod`.

Comment: У меня есть готовое решение, но я очень - *очень* - хотел бы, чтобы вы доделали сами. Половину ответа вы уже сами описали - этот метод должен быть статичным, вторая половина ответа - это то, что `i` должен сохраняться в классе (т.е. тоже быть статичным - у вас он правильно задан), а `__init__()` должен этот `i` обновлять, прибавляя единицу. В общем, в этом и все задание, больше всего мороки у меня случилось с тем, как работать со статикой из `__init__`, потому что я давно питон не трогал.

Comment: Весь написанный и выложенный мной код распространяется по лицензии MIT, которая разрешает свободное распространение кода (если я правильно понял, что имелся в виду какой-то мой вклад). Но, во-первых, из ревизий все равно уже ничего не удалится, во-вторых я не понимаю, где здесь хоть сколько-нибудь серьезный участок кода, который можно украсть.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628123/counting-instances-of-a-class

Comment: не то чтобы украсть, просто задача написана учителем для таких студентов как я, а внизу уже есть готовое решение которое выдается гулом @Etki

Answer (score 8):

У меня не хватает репутации на комментарий, но очень хочется тоже справиться с этой задачей, поэтому пишу вопрос в ответ. Я делаю так:

```
class CreatedInstancesCounter(object):
    i = 0 
    def __init__(self):
        self.i += 1

    @staticmethod
    def get_created_instances_count():
        return i
```

и у меня `i` после цикла в тесте равно 55, а не 56 (каким бы не было начальное значение `i`). Проблема в том, что я увеличиваю `i` через self? Других способов достучаться до переменной, не делая **init** статическим методом я не нашел, а если инит статичен, то питон говорит что `local variable 'i' referenced before assignment`. Подтолкните пожалуйста и меня в нужную сторону.

**UPD:** до меня дошло, поэтому делюсь ответом здесь же. Как в комментариях указал @Etki, метод get_created_instances_count возвращает глобальную переменную `i`, а не переменную класса, как я думал. Рабочим решением будет следующее:

```
class CreatedInstancesCounter(object):
    c = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.c += 1

    @classmethod
    def get_created_instances_count(cls):
        return cls.c
```

@classmethod позволяет принимать первым аргументом не экземпляр класса, а класс, таким образом к статической переменной класса можно обращаться путем cls.var_name, а не ClassName.var_name

Comment: Дело в двух вещах: 1. `return i` возвращает совсем не `self.i`, а результат `xrange` 2. вы увеличиваете `self.i` вместо `self.__class__.i` (хотя, возможно, `self.i` также является корректной записью - я не питонист)

Comment: @Etki Привет, проясни пожалуйста первый пункт 1) . Олсо, я тоже не питонист, но обращаться к class var через `CreatedInstancesCounter.i` - правильно. У меня всё работает и в 2, и в 3

Comment: @AndreyBuran насколько понимаю (лень копаться и дебажить), переменная `i` в данном примере берется внешняя, и проставляется она в `for i in xrange(56)`, поэтому на последней итерации она будет равняться 55. Через `self.__class__` я обращаюсь просто потому, что класс в определенный момент кто-то может захотеть переименовать.

Comment: @Etki Тогда без self. по крайней мере 3 этого не опнимает